# Ripple effect has a small delay that makes it invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am using `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on a `LinearLayout` (which acts as a button) to get the ripple effect. When this `button` is clicked, the current activity slides left during a transition. The problem is that the ripple effect takes some time to be triggered and at the time it becomes visibile, the activity transition has already started, which makes the use of the touch feedback completely useless. I don't want to add a delay to the activity transition, that would be stupid IMO.

XML file looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

How can I make the ripple effect useful and visible ?

Comment: can you show the onClick of LinearLayout?

Comment: Why ? It has nothing to do with the problem, I'm simply starting a new activity in the onClick method. The same delay occurs when the onClick is empty

Answer (score 2):

Try to use own drawable for background:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And ripple.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#80585554">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#your color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: It's working better even though it's not as fast as a simple selector. Do you know if it's possible to reduce the animation duration ?

Comment: Standard methods do not provide such an opportunity, but there are third-party libraries like https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. You can look at app:rv_rippleDuration attribute and how it implemented.

Comment: The animation in this library is not provided by the `<ripple>` tag, everything is done in java

Comment: I didn't see any improvement with this approach. A fast "click" still doesn't show any UI effect before the click-action performs the next step.

Answer (score 0):

On CardView you can apply

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true">
    <!--linearlayout etc...-->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: this doesn't improve the responsiveness of the ripple animation. I used this approach and definitely, the ripple takes 1 second to begin to show - by that time the next activity is already loading (or whatever else the button click does).

Answer (score 0):

The pressed state is delayed if one of the view's parents returns `true` in the `shouldDelayChildPressedState` method. Typically, subclasses of the `ViewGroup` that do not scroll should override this method and return `false`.